# binary search tree use in real world programs?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, binary-search-tree

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is binary search used in practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540165/where-is-binary-search-used-in-practice)
>   [What are the applications of binary trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees)

I have done various exercises involving adding,deleting,ordering and so on.

However i am having a hard time visualizing the use of binary search tree in real world programs. I mean sure it is way faster than some of the other algorithms for searching. But is this its only use ?

Could you give me some examples of this algorithm use in real world software.

Comment: Binary search != Binary search tree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use maps (or dictionaries) you are using binary search trees. This means that when you need to store arrays that look like

```
myArray["not_an_integer"] = 42;
```

you are probably using binary search trees.

In C++ for instance, you have the `std::map` and `std::hash_map` types. The first one is coded as a binary tree with `O(log(n))` insertion and lookup, whereas the second one is coded as a hash map (with `O(1)` lookup time).

**EDIT:** I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130416/what-are-the-applications-of-binary-trees). You should take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Space Partition is required in computer graphics. This uses Binary Search. More details are available at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning