# Binary Search on problems which contains some integers and not an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

Given a problem, How do we know if we have to apply binary search if the question has an integer?
For some obvious reasons, we know if the problem contains a sorted array, we apply binary search there. But there are tons of questions that do not have an array and still, binary search is applicable.

Comment: Can you please give examples of problems without an array and where binary search is applicable?

Comment: square root-https://leetcode.com/problems/sqrtx/
Arranging Coins-https://leetcode.com/problems/arranging-coins/

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540165/where-is-binary-search-used-in-practice

Comment: Sometimes you don't have an explicit sorted data structure to search in, but you have a **search space**. For instance, you might be looking for the solution of an equation in an interval. The interval is not an array, it's a "theoretical" space to search in, but you can still use binary search.

Comment: Those examples are *not* "binary search", rather the first is a simplified example of Newton's method and the second should *never* use any kind of search, binary or otherwise, but should just apply the quadratic equation to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for a value, and you can tell if a guess is too high or too low, then you can apply binary search to find the value.

Even the usual case of searching in a sorted array is like this -- we are searching for the index of the desired element in the array, and we can tell whether a guess is too high or too low, because the array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of binary search, the sorted array just represents a function that maps an input, we call it `index`, to an output that's monotonically ordered (increasing or decreasing) in correlation with the input.

So it doesn't matter for binary search if the function is

```
f(x) -> return the element at index x in an array
```

or

```
f(x) -> return 2 * x, for integer x // an example of a monotonically ordered function
```